# I can't update the md-autocomplete with debounce

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material, delay, debouncing

I've been with this for days.

I have a custom md-autocomplete component with:
    "@angular/core": "4.2.6",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.8",

I need launch the service call with a delay after pass 'n' seconds for the last key press. Everything is okay with Moock dates but, when I have a little delay from the service. BOOM!!!! the list doesn't appear.

```
  filterAutocomplete() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.autocompleteControl.valueChanges
      .startWith(null)
      // delay
      .debounceTime(this.autoProperties.time)
      // call service method
      .map(textSearch => this.FilterList(textSearch))
      // unique event
      .distinctUntilChanged();
  }

FilterList(textSearch: string): any[] {   
  this.ref.detectChanges();
  this.searchEmiter.emit(textSearch ? textSearch : ''); 
return this.listReg;
```

}

`this.filteredOptions` is used to paint the list in the view

`this.FilterList` launch an event to the father and there calls to service. Then, update the object with the parameters sent to the md-autocomplete

I tried to use `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` But doesn't update.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove even component even handler and add your own. That's easy.